# Fixing the filament tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have quite a few tags about filament:

- [filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filament)
- [plastic-filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastic-filament)
- [thermoplastic-filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermoplastic-filament)
- etc.

I feel like we need to clean these up and make clear what we'll use each tag for.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are there any plastics that would not be thermoplastics (that would be used in 3D printing)

Answer (score 6):

All filament used in 3D printing is thermoplastic filament, so plastic-filament and thermoplastic-filament are redundant.

Comment: Aren't all filaments plastic too? The tag 'plastic' seems redundant to me too. https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastic

Answer (score 3):

I see a form of hierarchy that could be used.

Depending on the question a higher level tag could be used or a more specific one for specific problems (or both tags even).

- Filament

  - Plastic Filament

    - ABS
    - PLA
  - Water Soluble

    - PVA
  - Flexible

    - NinjaFlex and similar
    - TPU
  - Conductive
  - Metalic
- Resin
- Powder
- Full Color

Feel free to edit to add more types

Comment: I really like this approach. One issue, though, is that if you put something under (for example) "TPU" , then someone who's searching for a parent category like "flexible" will miss it. Unless stackexchange has (or would implement) some automation for category hierarchies. Also, I'd suggest lengthening names since they'll be seen out of context.

Comment: I like the idea of a hierarchy, but how will that be displayed to users?  AFAIK all tags in SE's are independent of each other.

Comment: You could do somwthing like ABS-plastic-filament vs pla-plastic-filament

Comment: while hirarchy is ok and "flexible Filaments" as well as Conductive or water soluble make sense, the category of "plastic filament" is reduntdant.

Answer (score 3):

I bump this and propose the radical method:

We only need ONE [filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filament) tag and then any tags for specific material (e.g.[pla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pla) [abs](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abs) [petg](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/petg) [pva](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pva) [tpu](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpu) [pc](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc)) groups that have specific properties (e.g. [flexible-filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flexible-filament) [conductive-filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conductive-filament))

- The difference between [thermoplastic-filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermoplastic-filament) and [plastic-filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastic-filament) in use is nonexistant and both are pretty much identical to filament in the current use - it is rather random which one gets used, in many cases more than one is used.
- There is no filament that can be used in 3D printing that is not a thermoplastic, as the method to re-shape the filament via heat demands a thermoplastic.
- While there are clearly more plastics than thermoplastics, non thermoplastic plastics are not useable for 3D printing unless you would design a whole printer to use for example an UV-curing resin delivered to the workpiece via a needle - which makes this a non-FDM printer.

Comment: I think it is worth stating what makes this best - and I think in terms of categorising questions 'filament' is more than enough for the current level of detail that these questions seem likely to cover.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane added more

Comment: Looking at the [synonyms](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) page, thermoplastic-filament is a synonym of plastic-filament. Are you saying that they should be merged?

Comment: @greenonline pretty much