# Can we create a filament tag for flexibles? (TPE/TPU)

Tags: discussion, tags

Tag [nylon](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nylon) exists already, but I think it would be incredibly useful to have a TPE/TPU tag and a tag for all flexibles as a category.

**EDIT:** It has come to my attention that the tag [flexible](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flexible) already exists. I still would like to see a tag [tpu](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpu) though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[flexible](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flexible) could be used together with the [filament](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filament) to indicate the question is about flexible filament, but I understand that it may be beneficial to have separate TPE/TPU tags (it saves a tag). Furthermore, there are also tags for [pla](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pla), [abs](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abs), [pom](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pom) etc.

- TPE = **T**hermo**P**lastic **E**lastomer
- TPU = **T**hermo**P**lastic Poly**U**rethane, which is a type of thermoplastic elastomer

I suggest to make 2 tags [tpe](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpe) and [tpu](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpu) where the TPU tag is a synonym for tag TPE.

Comment: +1: I like that concept. Can we make that a reality?

Comment: @ifconfig The tags are already in place, we now need a moderator to make a synonym! Please join us on [chat] (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79830) you can reach a mod there!

Comment: Do we actually need a synonym? The reason I ask is, if TPU is a subset, but different from TPE, why not keep them separate. To me there should be no issue in doing so. People should not be confused by that if they are familiar with either filament, especially if the wiki is filled out for each. JMHO.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 from what I've read is that it exactly the same.

Comment: Is it ***exactly*** the same?

Answer (score 2):

From [What is the difference between TPE and TPU Flexible Filament?](https://rigid.ink/blogs/news/172062855-what-is-the-difference-between-tpe-and-tpu-flexible-filament)

> TPE = ThermoPlastic Elastomer
>
> TPU = Thermoplastic PolyUrethane, which is a type of ThermoPlastic Elastomer

which is as 0scar has already stated, i.e. TPU ∈ TPE. It goes on to say:

> Although technically classed under the ThermoPlastic Elastomer
> spectrum, the full name for TPU is ThermoPlastic Polyurethane. This
> isn’t especially new in industry, but until recently wasn’t commonly
> available in 3D printing.
>
> However recently it’s growing a lot more popularity among printers.
> While on the surface very similar to TPE, but TPU 3D printing has some
> notable differences.
>
> TPU is very similar in elasticity and other mechanical properties to
> TPE. Although it is very slightly more rigid, at Shore 94A-95A. This
> makes it a little easier to print in printers that don’t usually print
> the original, softer TPE 3D printing filament well, as the slight more
> rigidity is easier for the extruder mechanism to handle.

So they don't seem ***exactly*** the same. I dunno, I'm not sure. However, we apparently have the tags already, so that isn't a major issue anymore.

With regards to the synonym aspect: Are the questions going to to be the same, i.e. will the same issues happen to both TPU and TPE, or will TPU have special, particular issues? If the latter, then a synonym maybe isn't a good idea.

Regarding [flexible](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flexible), I wonder if it is necessary. Aren't we trying to reduce the number of filament tags? See [Fixing the filament tags](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/fixing-the-filament-tags). If having [flexible](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flexible) will help in this direction then all well and good, otherwise, maybe it isn't.

However, I'm not a filament expert. You can decide what you want to do and if you need me to do it, message me in chat or leave a comment.

Comment: Good points, @Greenonline. I actually agree with both arguments you make here.